# Converting string to int without losing the zero in the beginning

Tags: c#, string, format, int

I tried `int.parse,` and convert class to convert a string to int.

While I'm converting. I'm losing the 0 in the beginning which i don't want.

Ex : 09999 becomes 9999 - I don't want this.

I want to keep it as it is.

How can i do that?

Comment: Mathematically, the leading 0 is insignificant. 09999 and 9999 are equally nine thousand, nine hundred and ninety-nine. Why must you keep the leading zero if it's essentially the same number?

Comment: You want an integer representation with a leading zero?

Comment: This is confusing. Is this only for printing/display this integer's value?

Comment: Don't convert it to an `int`.

Comment: if you want do mathematical operations with it, just make a copy of string and cast it to int.

Comment: Doesn't a leading 0 denote octal notation? Thus 09999 is an invalid number...

Comment: I've got a situation where I need to take part of a string, convert it to an int, increment it, and then put it back in the string, but I always want there to be a certain number of leading zeroes. Some people just need specific formats. Why is this so hard to answer?

Comment: You could count the length of the String, then convert to int, do what you want with it, then go back to String and then add zeros to its beginning until its lenth is the same length as it was before.

Comment: You cannot. An int is meant to represent a mathematical integer. The numbers 09999 and 9999 are  the same number. Both are equivalent. Why you need this type of number format.
You would like to print it somewhere ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot.  An `int` is meant to represent a mathematical integer.  The numbers `09999` and `9999` are exactly the same number, mathematically.

Perhaps there is a different problem here.  Why do you need to do this?  Maybe there's a better way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 39):

```
myNumber.ToString("D5");
```

`//D` represents 'Decimal', and 5 is the specified amount of digits you want the number to be always. This will pad your value with zeroes until it reaches 5 digits.

Comment: You're literally the only peson who answered the question. Sometimes people just wanna format something in a specific way!

Comment: @DanCallahan thank you for actually answering this question, was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do something like always print your number with 5 places, it goes like

```
myNumber.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Answer (score 4):

No, `int.Parse("09999")` actually returns 0x0000270F.  Exactly 32 bits (because that's how big `int` is), 18 of which are leading zeros (to be precise, one is a sign bit, you could argue there are only 17 leading zeros).

It's only when you convert it back to a string that you get "9999", presence or absence of the leading zero in said string is controlled by the conversion back to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
// For our requirement that new ID's should be of same length as old ID's.
string strID = "002017";
int number = int.Parse(strID);
string newID = (++number).ToString("D" + strID.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot. you will have to maintain the value as a string if you want it to remain that way.

Answer (score 0):

Int values cannot have leading zeros

Comment: Half of all `int` values do have leading zeros (zero bits, that is).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just converting to int to test the value, keep the original data around and use the string value of it when you want the leading zeor. If you require the integer to have zero padding after mathematically working with it you will have to format it with sprintf or the like whenever you output it.

Answer (score 0):

you cant, but if you need to cast it to int and keep the zeros you can create a copy of it and then cast it to int, then you will have two versions of it one as int and one as string.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a old thread, but this can also help:

```
// convert to big integer
var bigIntBits = BigInteger.Parse(intNumber);
int indexOfOne = intNumber.IndexOf('1');            
string backToString = new string('0', indexOfOne) + bigIntBits.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem;
Solved it with an if else
Couldn't find another solution for it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).